# How to pass additional personalization data in a email from API call as a separate payload?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api

I have a Marketing Cloud Journey to be triggered via API for real time email sends when the customer make a specific action. At the same time, on the email that will be send via the API Journey, there must be elements included in the API call, for example a personalized URL to be send in the email to the corresponding Contact.
Ι need additional personalization data for email  and based on an older answer they wrote to me whatever it needs pass it in the API call as a separate attribute/payload .

My question is , if we proceed with this option, we can have the attributes to be used in the email within the initial API call that will trigger the Journey ? This only mean that within the API call pointing to the Journey Entry Source endpoint, a separate payload should be included so that we can fetch those data and trigger the Journey via the same API call ? If this is the case and we fetch those data in the same API call, how do we add those attributes in the email used in the API Journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is quite well-described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm). You can define a number of attributes in the payload, which can hold additional information for your journey. In below example, two attributes are added: one holding the URL, another holding the full name.

```json
{
    "ContactKey": "XYZ123",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"ActionReaction",
    "Data": {
        "personalisedURL":"https://www.example.com/helloworld",
        "customerName":"John Smith" }
}
```

You can basically include as many parameters as you need. DO keep in mind, that the names in the payload need to correspond to field names in journey's underlying data extension.

Comment: In our case, we want to send a different URL to each Contact email recipient. This mean that we should add all distinct URL parameters one by one?

Comment: @ThemisTsoupros since you will be injecting contacts individually, each payload will contain URL specific to that contact